# how to create ZSH alias/function for git commit, with prompt for user input to use as commit message?

Tags: git, function, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I've currently got a zsh alias which runs a function which you can see here:

```
function gac () {
  git add .; git commit -m "commit"
}
alias gac="gac"
```

this works fine and is somewhat useful however having a commit message of "commit" isn't useable for anything more than small personal projects.

how would i create a prompt in this function that asks for user input and then uses that user input as the commit message?

thanks!

Comment: You don't need the alias at all. The function is callable as-is.

Comment: @Cal : Just omit `-m commit` completely. `git` will then open a text editor an ask the user for entering a commit message. IMHO, it is perhaps more userfriendly to have the function accept the commit message as an optional parameter, and use it if it is supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the function to use an argument:

```
gac () {
    git add .
    git commit -m "$1"
}
```

Then use it as

```
gac "This is my message"
```

Or, you can just omit `-m` altogether and let your user enter a proper commit message in their text editor as usual.

```
gac () {
    git add .
    git commit
}
```

Comment: In bash I'd use `git commit ${1:+-m "$1"}`; if `$1` is empty the entire substitution is empty; if `$1` is not empty the substitution is `-m "$1"`.

Comment: Is that safe? The corner cases I can think of where not quoting the expansion would cause problems seem to be handled correctly by `"$1"`, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Yes, i think it's safe because in `-m "$1"` the parameter `$1` is quoted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks went for the first option, wasn't aware of how to use args in zsh. appreciate your help!